# Cause of delay in CAN

Tags: sensor, parallel, can, python

I am dealing with a differential drive robot that interacts with several motors and actuators, all through a powerful [NVIDIA Jetson Xavier](https://www.nvidia.com/en-in/autonomous-machines/embedded-systems/jetson-agx-xavier/). The Jetson runs Ubuntu and I use Python3 for programming all actions of the robot that go through a microcontroller via CAN bus.

Now, there are multiple parts of the robot that we need to program; chiefly **navigation** and **arm-movement**. Right now, the robot does only either of them, i.e., it can either move or perform some arm-movement. **All the actions are based on the same 1D LiDAR sensor.**
[image]
To boost its speed, I thought of performing both these functions in parallel, as they are *almost* independent of the other. Python provides two wonderful options for this: [multi-processing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). Both of them *seem* equally good options with the caveat that threads cannot be killed and prove negligible improvement when compared to multi-processing. So, I am staying with multi-processing for the time-being.

Now, the way I use the sensor or lidar values is, to get them via a thread and continuously dump them as global variables.

```
t = Thread(target=dump_lidar_data,args=())
t.start()
```

Various functions defined in the same file, use these values as:

```
def fun():
    global lidar1
    print(f'Look, I too can access lidar 1 values: {lidar1}')
```

The main process or the parent process detects when its show time and spawns two child processes: `p_navigation` and `p_arm`. Both these process start together and have their own instance of `dump_lidar` working in their respective processors. Both terminate on the basis of the same condition. In the meantime, the parent process does nothing.
[image]

I notice that there is a considerable delay (upto 1s) between the data procured by the `dump_lidar` in the parent process as compared to the ones in the child processes. It is also possible that the CAN bus is giving the data after a certain delay.

#### Is there a possibility that the CAN or the circuit involved in getting the data to the Jetson, cause this delay ?

Comment: Showing how your Linux fluff is built is probably not very relevant. Monitor the CAN traffic and see if that's a bottleneck: how often does messages get sent out, how high is the bus load etc. Assuming point-to-point, you should have close to 100% bus load. If so, the problem is too much data. Otherwise the problem is your Linux/Python fluff being too slow or unreliable to be used with realtime systems.

Comment: "I thought of performing both these functions in parallel"  Ok but you can only send one CAN message at a time. (How) do you synchronize control commands in the MCU?

Comment: The navigation and arm have separate can buses 0 & 1 respectively. Although it is possible that the arm alone may be flooding its can bus but I can confirm that. How should I monitor ?

Comment: Monitor with your CAN listener, which is a mandatory tool when doing any form of CAN development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transfer of a max. sized CAN frame is roughly ~100µs (at 1MBit/s). Everything else I guess is SW. But Linux + phyton is not a Realtime environment or fast in first place. You need at least a core with FiFo scheduling policy, and get rid of python - use compiled language like C++. But even that might just bring a minor improvement. You might need a real RTOS (beneath Linux) to have control over Sysclock, Interrupts, DMA,...